# F# If statement type mismatch

Tags: list, recursion, error-handling, f#

i am in a bit of a pickle, i have tried for 2 hours straight trying to get this code to work and im lost.

```
let DropColumn list =
    if List.exists List.isEmpty list then "empty value"
    else
    list |> List.map List.tail
```

This gives me an error *error FS0001: The type 'string' does not match the type ''a list'*

Comment: "empty value" is a string. `List.map` returns a list.  The if \ else blocks must return the same data type.

Comment: Yes , thats what i figured however how can i workaround this issue?

Comment: You can't work around something that makes no sense. The fix here will depend on what you actually need to do with the return value. I can think of at least four solutions that could work: 1) return the original list, 2) return an empty list, 3) return an option, 4) raise an exception.

Comment: it is hard to tell what you are trying to do with this function. `if` expression returns two different data types. which one is correct? string or list? what do you pass to this function? what you are trying to check? what you are trying to return?

Comment: well, im trying to make it essentially "gracefully" fail, in the sense that i dont want to raise an exception with "failswith" but i want the function to spew out error output, preferrably custom error message

Comment: Then I'd suggest using the result type. Give me a minute to write an answer suggesting how to use that.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to deal with failure in functional programming is to use the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results) type, which is essentially defined as:

```
type Result<'T,'TError> =
    | Ok of 'T
    | Error of 'TError
```

To apply it to your code we can just wrap the `string` in the unhappy path with `Error` and the `list` from the happy path with `Ok`:

```
let DropColumn list =
    if List.exists List.isEmpty list then
        Error "empty value"
    else
        list |> List.map List.tail |> Ok
```

Then to use it you can use pattern matching:

```
match DropColumn myList with
| Ok newList ->
    newList
| Error message ->
    printfn "Error occurred: %s" message
    []
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @glennsl is correct and in many cases the preferred way. However, I'd like to add that there are two other common ways of dealing with invalid input:

- Raise an exception. Use this for exceptional cases only, i.e. where you expect your code to halt as the result of invalid data. Do not use it for normal validation where you expect that data can often be wrong.
- Use `option`. This is similar to using `Result`, but doesn't maintain information for the invalid case. This approach is very common and used a lot in library functions like `List.tryFind`, `List.tryHead` etc.

#### Raise an exception

In the comments you show you already know this option exists, but let's give it here for completeness:

```
let dropColumnOrRaise list =
    if List.exists List.isEmpty list then failwith "empty value"
    else
    list |> List.map List.tail
```

#### Use `option`

This method usually requires that the business logic that shows an error or does recovery, goes elsewhere.

```
let tryDropColumn list =
    if List.exists List.isEmpty list then None
    else
    list 
    |> List.map List.tail
    |> Some
```

Use it as follows:

```
match tryDropColumn myCols with
| Some columns -> 
     // do something with valid columns, i.e., display them
     printfn "%i columns remaining (List.length (List.head myCols))"
| None -> 
     // error recovery or showing a message
     printfn "No column selected"
```

When you are dealing with several functions that operate on data that all return `option`, you can pipe them together with `Option.bind` (or `Option.map` if a function doesn't return `option`).

```
myCols
|> tryDropColumn
|> Option.map logColumns      // function that always succeeds
|> Option.bind tryAtLeastTwoColumns  // function that returns None on 1 or 0
|> Option.map showColumns
```

The code above removes the need to have a `match x with` for each returned `option`. Similar code can be used for `Result` from the previous answer.